# When restoring a network, an operation cannot be found in the restored graph

Tags: tensorflow

Using TensorFlow 1.9, I want to train a neural network in one Python file, and then restore the network using a different Python file. I have tried to do this using a simple example, but when I try to load my "prediction" operation, I receive an error. Specifically, the error is: `KeyError: "The name 'prediction' refers to an Operation not in the graph."`.

Below is my Python file to train and save the network. It generates some example data and trains a simple neural network, then saves the network every epoch.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

input_data = np.zeros([100, 10])
label_data = np.zeros([100, 1])
for i in range(100):
    for j in range(10):
        input_data[i, j] = i * j / 1000
    label_data[i] = 2 * input_data[i, 0] + np.random.uniform(0.01)

input_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10], name='input_placeholder')
label_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1], name='label_placeholder')

x = tf.layers.dense(inputs=input_placeholder, units=10, activation=tf.nn.relu)
x = tf.layers.dense(inputs=x, units=10, activation=tf.nn.relu)
prediction = tf.layers.dense(inputs=x, units=1, name='prediction')

loss_op = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(prediction - label_placeholder))
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(loss_op)

saver = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for epoch_num in range(100):
        _, loss = sess.run([train_op, loss_op], feed_dict={input_placeholder: input_data, label_placeholder: label_data})
        print('epoch ' + str(epoch_num) + ', loss = ' + str(loss))
        saver.save(sess, '../Models/model', global_step=epoch_num + 1)
```

And below is my Python file to restore the network. It loads the input and output placeholders, together with the operation required for making predictions. However, even though I have named an operation as `prediction` in the training code above, the code below cannot seem to find this operation in the loaded graph.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

input_data = np.zeros([100, 10])
for i in range(100):
    for j in range(10):
        input_data[i, j] = i * j / 1000

with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('../Models/model-99.meta')
    saver.restore(sess, '../Models/model-99')
    graph = tf.get_default_graph()
    input_placeholder = graph.get_tensor_by_name('input_placeholder:0')
    label_placeholder = graph.get_tensor_by_name('label_placeholder:0')
    prediction = graph.get_operation_by_name('prediction')
    pred = sess.run([prediction], feed_dict={input_placeholder: input_data})
```

Why can this code not find this operation, and what should I do to correct my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to modify a single line in your loading script (tested with tf 1.8):

```
prediction = graph.get_tensor_by_name('prediction/BiasAdd:0')
```

You have to specify which tensor you want to access, as prediction is only the namespace for the dense layer. You can check the exact name during saving with `prediction.name`. And when restoring, use `tf.get_tensor_by_name` as you are interested in the value, not the operation producing it.